# Opening new tabs in browser on the very right

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to force new tabs to open at the end of the tab bar (or second position on the right, skipping one tab with excel), not by modifying web browser preferences? I always have opened excel in the tab on the right and new tabs go in between which drives me crazy.

The line that now opens new tabs looks like this:

```
window.open(searchURL, "_blank", "noopener")
```

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. Could you explain what 'skipping one tab with excel' means?

Comment: You mean, in the "tab bar" in your browser UI, you want this "inserted" in a specific position? No, you have absolutely no influence on that whatsoever.

Comment: sorry, it cut out half of my explanation. I meant that the script opens new tabs with queries which are positioned next to current tab(with the tool). I always have opened excel in the tab on the right and new tabs go in between but I want them to open at the end of the tab bar.

Comment: No I've editted that out because it had no importance/significance to the actual question

Comment: Depending on the browser, there may not even be a notion of "left" or "right" (think old iOS Safari), so… no.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I couldn't find anything about it on the Internet, and this is my second week of learning coding :)